# RefererNotAllowedMapError Google Map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Yesterday I tried to put a GoogleMap on a website (javascript), but I am still getting the Google Maps API error: `RefererNotAllowedMapError`.

The following steps I have taken:

- Created credentials for this website (request an APi Key and add referrer in the API Manager. Accepted request from these HTTP referres is set to `*.thewebsitedomein.nl/*`)
- Verify the domain of the website (added a CNAME record in the DNS record)

But I am still getting this `RefererNotAllowedMapError`.

Regenerating a new key didn't help, can someone please help me?
Is there something I forgot to do?

Thanks!
AHF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding a new CNAME record (without the www) in the DNS and verifying the website again, the Google map is displayed without javascript errors.

Comment: CNAME for apex of a domain is not a good idea: https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain. It can break your email for example.

Answer (score 0):

From the Google Maps [Error Messages](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages) documentation itself,

> RefererNotAllowedMapError means that the current URL loading the
>   Google Maps JavaScript API has not been added to the list of allowed
>   referrers. Please check the referrer settings of your API key on the
>   Google API Console.

Also check this related SO questions:

- [Google Maps JavaScript API RefererNotAllowedMapError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288250/google-maps-javascript-api-referernotallowedmaperror)
- [Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508763/google-maps-api-error-referernotallowedmaperror)

Comment: Hi!
In my first post I already mentoined the URL for accepted requests from these HTTP referrers is set to `code`*.thewebsitedomein.nl/*`code`

Answer (score 0):

See screen dump for the settings

[image: See screen dump for the settings]